# How to make my FXML file show up on a window?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am making the GUI of my project using SceneBuilder. I have JavaFx knowledge but minimal FXML knowledge. I have build my parent window, my controller class, and my main class. My parent window, AdminView, is supposed to have a functional button which leads to another window. However, I am experiencing trouble with getting the parent window to even show up.

I considered that maybe it is an issue with the library or the URL reference. But I don't know enough about the topic to know what to do.

My main class:

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/view/Adminview.fxml"));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public abstract class AdminViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private void Button(ActionEvent event) {
        {
            try {
                Parent AdminViewParent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/application/view/Addhotel.fxml"));
                Scene AdminViewScene = new Scene(AdminViewParent);

                Stage window = (Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

                window.setScene(AdminViewScene);
                window.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Exceptions:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$154(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at view.AdminView.start(AdminView.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application view.AdminView
C:\Users\loku\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: Indeed there is an issue with the `location` url: It's not provided (`null`). Your path is wrong or the resource is not indluced in the classpath at runtime...

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Class extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/Folder/File.fxml"));
        loader.setController(LoginController.class);

        Parent parent = loader.load();

        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This always worked for me! Use this when you want to open a new window!
Use this if you want to add a FXML to a pane:

```
public void showFXML() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

        loader.setLocation(this.getClass().getResource("/layout/YourFXML.fxml"));
        loader.setController(new YourController());
        //yourController = loader.getController();

        yourParent = loader.load();

        //yourMainController.getPane().getChildren().clear();
        yourMainController.getPane().getChildren().add(yourParent);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Then this is my controller:

```
public class Controller {
@FXML
Pane pane;

@FXML
Button button;

@FXML
private void buttonOnClicked() {
    doSomething()
}
}
```

For this you must add the method names in scenebuilder under 'code'.

I hope I could help you!